# Remove registration from web application (EF, ASP.NET Identity, Azure) and register a user from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-identity

I want to publish a sample web application. I don't want any new users to register, just to have a single user who will be able to login for testing purposes. I have a running default ASP.NET Identity module added to app having a LocalDb.

Now I want to put it on Azure. I was just going to remove the "Register" controller, but DB is going to be created automatically by Entity Framework. As passwords are stored hashed in the DB - there seems to be no way for me to enter this single users' password from within DB.

I know now that I complicated this far too much, I should have just stored these credentials in code - as there is not a great benefit from securing this application, but since I have already done this - maybe somebody would have an idea if there would be an option to create a username and password from within DB overcoming the password hash?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but why not check for the user in the startup of the web application and create it when it does not already exist?

Comment: this sounds like a good idea!

Comment: If you're using Code First with EF, then you can easily seed the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily seed this user account via Entity Framework migrations - specifically the `Seed(...)` method.

With migrations enabled, you can create a `Configuration` class along the lines of the following:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourEFContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "YourEFContext";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    protected override void Seed(YourEFContext context)
    {
        CreateUserIfNotExists(context, "someuser@email.com", "the_password");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just call directly into ASP.Net Identity to check if the user exists
    /// If not, create them
    /// </summary>
    private static void CreateUserIfNotExists(YourEFContext context, string email, string password)
    {
        // Use your application user class here
        var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        // We're using email for the username
        if ((um.FindByEmail(email)) == null)
        {
            var au = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = email,
                Email = email
            };

            var res = um.Create(au);

            if (res.Succeeded)
            {
                um.AddPassword(au.Id, password);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create user: {0}", res.Errors.FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Seed(...)` will run at the end of every migration, so we simply check to see if our user exists, and if not, create them and assign the known password.

Comment: thank you Brendan, I'm working on it where I use this scenario or very similar, but the Seed method does not seem to be called by default from Identity. It looks like I should setup the seed from Global.asax ?Like Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new DbInitializer());

        }
internal class DbInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>{}

Comment: No - when you run a migration it will get executed. Thus could be when you run `uodate-database` from the package manager console, or if you configure up automatic migrations.  Running from global will execute everytime the AppPool recycles.